# Execute doGet in Servlet from java prgram

Tags: java, servlets

I try execute method doGet (just show popup) in servlet from java program.

Code in java program:

```
URL url = new URL( "http://localhost:9999/xxx/screen?msg=VVU6" ); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); 
line = in.readLine(); 
System.out.println( line ); 
in.close();
```

Code in doGet:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>");
out.println("alert('peek-a-boo');");
out.println("</script>");
```

But, when run it not show popup alert, it just print data in console.

May you help me in this case ?

Thanks all!

Comment: There's no way to display browser popup using J2SE program.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You interact with an URL from java code using Selenium Web driver : http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written in doGet writes the markup you have written to the `outputstream`. When the URL mapped to the servlet is hit from a web browser or a browser equivalent(web drivers or in-memory browsers for example), it will be rendered as a `html markup`.

Read the basics of J2EE servlet and JSP to get a clear understanding of the usage and use case. A console cannot be used to generate popups.

Answer (score 0):

*pre-condition*: your Servlet is running in a Servlet Container (Jetty, Tomcat)  at http://localhost:9999/xxx

If your routing is correct, (you access the doGet method in your Servlet by pointing your browser at http://localhost:9999/xxx/screen) you should be able to see the alert with:

```
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.println("<html><head></head><body>");
  out.println("<script>alert('peek-a-boo');</script>");
  out.println("</body></html>");
```

If you wanna perform the GET from a JavaSE program please give a look to any small REST Client library like [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html) to be up to speed quickly.